# Is there a lower level log of USB activity than Console.app or system.log?

Tags: usb, logs, console

I'm plugging in a USB device which should be a USB/serial adapter. In addition to it not seeming to work, plugging and unplugging it produces absolutely no output in Console.app or /var/log/system.log. Is there any lower level place I can look to see what's happening when I plug it in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the usbutils commands via `macport` (sorry, I don't use `brew`)

```
sudo port install usbutils
```

then, for a first check, try the following command:

```
lsusb
```

You should see a list of your USB devices. It might be hard for you to identify your device. A good way to filter all your devices is to remove every of them except your USB/serial adapter.

If `lsusb` returns nothing. Your device is dead.

If my memory is good, the name of an USB-serial adapter printed ends by:

```
 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```